# How to check if a value in a row is empty in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df which I read from a json file:

`val df = spark.read.json("C:\\filepath\\file.json")` which have the following data

| Id | downloadUrl | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 52193 | https://... | Title... |
| 5441 | https://... | Title... |
| 5280 | null | null |
| 5190 | https://... | Title... |
| 5215 | https://... | Title... |
| 1245 | https://... | Title... |
| 339 | null | Editorial |
| 59 | https://... | Title... |

Now I want to create a new dataframe or rdd that only have rows downloadUrl and title not null.

```
  df.map(row=>{
    // here I want to see if the downloadUrl is null
    // do something

    // else if the title is null
    // do something

    // else
    // create a new dataframe df1 with a new column "allowed" with the value set to 1 
    // push df1 to API

  })
```

Comment: if you're not going to use in that map method an external scala library it's better to use the dataframe API. Is much faster and spark can optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  df.map(row=>{
    // here I want to see if the downloadUrl is null
    // do something

    // else if the title is null
    // do something

    // else
    // create a new dataframe df1 with a new column "allowed" with the value set to 1 
    // push df1 to API
  })
```

Not sure what you mean by ***if title/downloadUrl is null do something***

But if you want a new dataframe that only have rows downloadUrl and title not null. Try using this dataset method

```
case class MyObject(id:Int, downloadUrl: String, title: String)
val df = spark.read.json("C:\\filepath\\file.json").as[MyObject]
val df1 = df.filter(o => o.downloadUrl =! null && o.title != null)
```

Another way would be using the filter function as below

```
val df1 = df.filter(row=>{
    val downloadUrl = row.getAs[String]("downloadUrl")
    val title = row.getAs[String]("title")
    // here I want to see if the downloadUrl is null
    // do something

    // else if the title is null
    // do something

    // else
    // create a new dataframe df1 with a new column "allowed" with the value set to 1 
    return title != null && downloadUrl != null
  })
```

**Lastly** if you want to push reach row to an external API, use a foreach each instead. Then use the predicate to determine whether the row should be pushed

```
  df.foreach(row=>{
    val downloadUrl = row.getAs[String]("downloadUrl")
    val title = row.getAs[String]("title")
    // here I want to see if the downloadUrl is null
    // do something

    // else if the title is null
    // do something

    // else
    // create a new dataframe df1 with a new column "allowed" with the value set to 1 
    if (title != null && downloadUrl != null){
        //call the API here
    }
  })
```

But in this case we are not creating a new dataframe - df1